# How to modify filters in gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I am able to create an `AND` filter in Gmail:

```
from:amy to:may
```

How do I create an `O`R filter like the following:

```
from:amy OR to:amy
```

Is it possible to create an `OR` filter using the "Create new filter wizard" or do I have to manually edit an existing filter? If so, how?

Comment: So your saying you want to know how to make the filter an `OR` condition rather then an `and` condition?

Comment: @fogest exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make an or condition just simply make two filters. It's possible to use the `or` condition in one of the lines for example:

> From: a@a.com OR b@b.com

But you cannot have an OR statement for two different fields such as `From` and `To`.

I believe creating two filters though one, containing only the from and the other containing only the to. Yes it may require a few more seconds of work but that's the best your going to get for now.

OR try this:

1. Create or modify a filter.
2. In the **Has the words field**, enter your OR
       condition. For example: `to:user@example.com` OR `From:user@example.com`

Comment: `To make an or condition just simply make two filters`, yep so far this is what I've been doing, i don't like it at all. That' why posted this question here. I'll leave the question open for some time any other answers.

Comment: @iamcreasy I found another question similar to your but less specific. Will edit my question in with a answer that may help you more.

Comment: Noup, doesn't work. I guess, **Has the words field** doesn't take query.

Comment: @iamcreasy so you made sure that you did it just like the example? If that doesn't work then unfortunately you will need to just create two filters.

Comment: I noticed something strange, GMail add up two condition like they were on their respective field.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand?

Comment: `from > abc` and `Has the words > to:abc` results in search query `from:abd to:abc`

Comment: Yes exactly that is why if you did Has the words with to:abc OR from:abd it should work!

Comment: Nice to here...!

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on any search query string at all. Simply type the search query

```
from:amy OR to:amy
```

into the search box, then click the dropdown arrow to open the options, and click the link to "create filter with this search."

Alternatively, you can enter any query with search operators in the "has the words" field. Feel free to get complicated:

```
((from:amy -to:mom) OR (to:amy -from:me)) -subject:halloween
```

Comment: When I click "create filter with this search" with `from:amy OR to:amy`, the query gets messed up, and becomes something like this, `from:amy to:amy OR`.

Comment: I agree with @Sarah. These steps work as described for me. The filter ends up in the "Has the words" box. If yours is changing for some reason in an odd way, try just typing "from:amy OR to:amy" into the "Has the words" box at that point in the Create Filter wizard. I think that may help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the OR at all: simply put the a@a.com into "Has the words" field and it returns them all, both to: and from:

Comment: Yes, that's another way. :) Thank you.